# null in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

Whenever i click on run project , it is showing me `NullPointerException : null`.
I don't know what is the reason, why am i getting this?

[image]

**NOTE** Dont point this question as duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), because i am not getting null in any control or view or any line of code.

**Edit :** 
I am using Android Studio 1.4 with following gradle configuration :

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

Comment: What message getting in Messages Tab?

Comment: @DavidS do you really think after having 5000+ reputation i will post that kind of question which are very famous in android?

Comment: @DavidS - That duplicate would only apply if the **running code** had a null pointer

Comment: Anyways... [Locating IDE log files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) may be worth a read

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i am getting same thing in message also, like NullpointerException : null (before 1min ago)

Comment: It could be an internal IDE error. Did you try restarting android studio?

Comment: Oh, my apologies. You are all right. I did not read the question closely enough, and I did not realize this was the IDE. (In my defense, this would not have been the first time a question claimed it wasn't a duplicate  when it was.)

Comment: Have a look in the `idea.log` file. This is the path for me `C:\Users\UserX\.AndroidStudio1.5\system\log`. @cricket_007, I didnt know there was a shortcut to this. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you all , `Invalidate and Restart` did trick for me, it is solved by that. Only restarting studio and system was not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Strange** I was finding for solution from more that 2 hours but solution was simple. I have tried with restarting system as well as Android Studio, but the thing which did trick for me is `Invalidate and Restart`.

you can find this option from **File->Invalidate caches/Restart.**

[image]

This did trick for me and now its not showing error.

Comment: Where in the menu of Android Studio you find this window?

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, I had the same issue, but Invalidation didn't helped. I even tried to reinstall Android Studio but it didn't help either.

Finally, I removed `.idea` folder and all other files from Android studio (`*.iml`) and re-imported project as a Gradle project and everything became fine.

I had Android Studio version 2.3